# ifelse in R: If either 3 conditions evaluated on 3 vectors is true, add a constant to all vectors

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm looking to write a conditional statement using ifelse, that will evaluate 3 conditions on 3 vectors simultaneously. If either of the conditions are true, along the vectors, I like to add a constant to all three vectors.

Here is an example dataset:

```
a<-c(rep(0,5),rep(1,2))
b<-c(rep(0,6),rep(1,1))
c<-rep(5,7)
(data <- cbind(a,b,c))

     a b c
[1,] 0 0 5
[2,] 0 0 5
[3,] 0 0 5
[4,] 0 0 5
[5,] 0 0 5
[6,] 1 0 5
[7,] 1 1 5
```

For each row, if a, b, or c is zero, I would like to add a constant k = 0.5 to the values.

Here is my expected dataset after the conditional statement:

```
k <- 0.5

     exp.a exp.b exp.c
[1,]   0.5   0.5   5.5
[2,]   0.5   0.5   5.5
[3,]   0.5   0.5   5.5
[4,]   0.5   0.5   5.5
[5,]   0.5   0.5   5.5
[6,]   1.5   0.5   5.5
[7,]   1.0   1.0   5.0
```

I tried something along the lines of:

```
(exp.a <- (a + ifelse((a == 0), k, 0)))
```

The code above does not evaluate vectors b and c if they are zero, so it is not what I'm looking for. How may I write the ifelse statement so that all 3 vectors will be evaluated if the value at each row is zero, and if any of them is zero, add a constant k to all values in the row?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one vectorized possibility. In general, if you only have one condition (equals to `0`), you don't really need multiple `ifelse` statements, you can just sum the rows that equal to `0` and assign only to them

```
indx <- rowSums(data == 0L)
data[indx > 0L, ] <- data[indx > 0L, ] + 0.5
data
#        a   b   c
# [1,] 0.5 0.5 5.5
# [2,] 0.5 0.5 5.5
# [3,] 0.5 0.5 5.5
# [4,] 0.5 0.5 5.5
# [5,] 0.5 0.5 5.5
# [6,] 1.5 0.5 5.5
# [7,] 1.0 1.0 5.0
```

Alternatively, you could try the `data.table` package which could probably do this more memory efficient (if your matrix is big) and update your columns by reference

```
library(data.table)
data <- as.data.table(data)
data[rowSums(data == 0L) > 0L, names(data) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x + 0.5)][]
#      a   b   c
# 1: 0.5 0.5 5.5
# 2: 0.5 0.5 5.5
# 3: 0.5 0.5 5.5
# 4: 0.5 0.5 5.5
# 5: 0.5 0.5 5.5
# 6: 1.5 0.5 5.5
# 7: 1.0 1.0 5.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is simple and works well with what I was trying to achieve. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using a for loop:

```
a<-c(rep(0.0,5),rep(1.0,2))
b<-c(rep(0.0,6),rep(1.0,1))
c<-rep(5.0,7)
(data <- cbind(a,b,c))

k <- 0.5

for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  if(any(data[i,]==0))
    data[i,] <- data[i,] + k
}

data
       a   b   c
[1,] 0.5 0.5 5.5
[2,] 0.5 0.5 5.5
[3,] 0.5 0.5 5.5
[4,] 0.5 0.5 5.5
[5,] 0.5 0.5 5.5
[6,] 1.5 0.5 5.5
[7,] 1.0 1.0 5.0
```